# URL encode/decode on file name replace spaces with +, need alternative.

Tags: java, html, utf-8

My product is a web application.
I have files that I upload and download later on, to/from my server.
I am using **java.net.URLDecoder.decode()** when uploading files with unicode characters and **java.net.URLDecoder.encode()** when downloading files in order to save the file name and finally return it to the client as expected with no question marks and stuff (?????) .
The problem is that if the file name consists spaces then the encode/decode replace them with **+** character which is perfectly normal because that's their business implementation, but clearly as you can understand it does not fit to my purpose.
The question is what alternative do I have to overcome this situation?
Is there build-in method for that or 3rd party package?

Comment: And where do you insert that filename? Is that in a URI query string, fragment part, other?

Comment: Is `+` not decoded as space`? One could replace the plus after encoding with `%20`.

Comment: @JoopEggen that won't work all the time; consider for instance that `+` is legal in a URI fragment

Comment: I am inserting the file name to the response header of the http response.

Comment: In a header? Uhwell, just surround the filename with double quotes in all situations, then! You don't even need to encode them

Comment: Double quotes? Can you post an example here please?

Comment: Well, `"my filename with spaces.txt"`

Comment: Ok, I understand what you wrote here but my problem is Unicode characters. I cannot just put the string as is to header, because then I will see the file as follow: "????.txt" or "----.txt". That is why I used the encode/decode functions from the first place, but they are not handling with spaces.

Comment: If the other end cannot see the characters properly, it means you have another problem to begin with, and that is correct header character coding! If headers are UTF-8 this is not a problem. Anyway -- go with Guava, you can't go wrong.

Comment: See this posts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11213160/sending-utf-8-values-in-http-headers-results-in-mojibake http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432233/asp-net-download-file-with-japanese-file-name

Comment: You can see that they are using the same encode/decode to solve the same problem but they will have the same problem as I have when spaces are involve in the file name

Comment: So, basically, you need to write your own Unicode escaper -- easy with Guava ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cure!
I was just needed to use **java.net.URI** for that:

```
public static String encode(String urlString) throws UnsupportedEncodingException
{
    try
    {
        URI uri = new URI(urlString);
        return uri.toASCIIString();
    }
    catch (URISyntaxException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The **toASCIIString()** escapes the special characters so when the string arrives to the browser it is shown correctly.

Answer (score 3):

You don't tell where this filename is used. The characters to encode will be different whether, for instance, it is in a URI query string or fragment part.

You probably want to have a look at Guava's (15.0+) [`Escaper`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v16.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/escape/Escaper.html)s; and, in particular here, `UnicodeEscaper` implementations and its derived class `PercentEscaper`. Guava already provides a few of them usable in various parts of URLs.

EDIT: here is how to do with Guava:

```
public final class FilenameEscaper
    extends PercentEscaper
{
    public PercentEscaper()
    {
        super("", false);
    }
}
```

Done! See [here](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v16.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/net/PercentEscaper.html). Of course, you may want to declare that some more characters than the default ones are safe.

Also have a look at [RFC 5987](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5987) to make a better encoder.

Comment: The thing is that it is not a URL neither URI it is just a file name with Unicode characters that I set in the response header when the user download the file, so he will see the file name correctly.

Comment: See my comment above then. You don't need any sort of encoding, just to surround the file name with double quotes

Answer (score 3):

You could also convert a space to %20.

See: [URL encoding the space character: + or %20?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634271/url-encoding-the-space-character-or-20)

There are also various other Java libraries that do URL encoding, with %20. Here are a two examples:

Guava:

```
UrlEscapers.urlPathSegmentEscaper().escape(urlToEscape);
```

Spring Framework:

```
UriUtils.encodePath(urlToEscape, Charsets.UTF_8.toString());
```

Comment: Please see my last comment above it will explain you the problem.

Comment: You could try to encode header text like suggested in RFC 2047. Not sure if support is good for this though. javax.mail.internet.MimeUtility is able to do this conversion.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/324470/http-headers-encoding-decoding-in-java

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
URLEncoder.encode(someString, "UTF-8").replace("+", "%20");
```

Comment: Except when the `+` is actually a _safe_ character to use!

Comment: I think that `+` will be encoded into `%2B` before `replace` method.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem with spaces. Combination of URL and URI solved it:

```
URL url = new URL("file:/E:/Program Files/IBM/SDP/runtimes/base");
URI uri = new URI(url.getProtocol(), url.getUserInfo(), url.getHost(), url.getPort(), url.getPath(), url.getQuery(), url.getRef());
```

* Please note that [URLEncoder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) is used for web forms `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` mime-type - not http network addresses.

* Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/749829/435605